# How to transfer a integer value between multiple Jframes

Tags: java, netbeans

i'm new to NetBeans and Java and general and i was just wondering how i could use my values across multiple Jrames.

I first declared my variable with in the first Jframe

```
public class GUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {

int Num1;
int Num2;
int Num3;
```

I then made it so that these integers could be updated by using textfields and a save button.

```
private void saveNumbersMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                       
    Num1 = Integer.parseInt(Field1.getText ());
    Num2 = Integer.parseInt(Field2.getText());
    Num3 = Integer.parseInt(Field3.getText());

}
```

Now i want to display these results in labels in  different Jframes but i'm not quite sure how to execute this. Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you :)

Comment: The answer will depend a little on when you want to use the values.  You could, for example, pass the values to the class via it's constructor when you create it or, if the objects are already created, you could use "getters" and "setters" (which are just methods) to pass the information between instances of the frames. You can have a look at [Passing Information to a Method or a Constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

If you are printing them to a component, you must update the text on the label if you wish to see the results.

Your code should work, but after that you must re-set the text on the entity you wish to see it on

Answer (score -1):

One thing you can do is make them `public static`:

```
public static int Num1;
public static int Num2;
public static int Num3;
```

This means that you can access them using `GUI.Num1`, `GUI.Num2`, etc. If you can access an instance of `GUI`, then you don't need to make them `static`.